# Do I need to own Diablo III to download and install the game?

Tags: diablo-iii

When I purchased the digital version of *Diablo III*, I was given a passkey to download it.

While I know I need a Battle.net account with *Diablo III* activated on it to play the game, does this passkey mean I need to own the game in order to even download and install it? If not, can I give my passkey out, or is it only usable one time? If it is a one-time download, is there another way to download the game without the use of passkeys?

Answer (score 7):

The download for the installer is not a one time download. In fact, Blizzard themselves do occasionally [link directly to the installer](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/blog/4410912/New_Downloaders_for_English_and_German-12_05_2012#blog). The license however is only usable on your Battle.net account, so your friend will need a license as well.

Answer (score 0):

This "someone else" will still require their own license tied to their Battle.net account, else they would not be able to log in to play.

Answer (score 0):

You are able to download it with the passkey an unlimited amount of times.

However, the CD key is tied to your BattleNet account, which you will have to log in in the login screen of Diablo 3.