# Installing Diablo 3 on multiple computers

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do I need to own Diablo III to download and install the game?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/70374/do-i-need-to-own-diablo-iii-to-download-and-install-the-game)

I have read on other questions that you're allowed to install Diablo 3 on as many computers as you want but I have tested this and it's not true.

I have a copy installed on my Mac and I downloaded it for my PC but upon installation the Blizzard website launched asking me to login. After I logged in it asked for the cdkey (I had downloaded this from Blizzard - I didn't order a cd)

I looked around on the Blizzard website and don't see a cdkey anywhere. I also checked my email to see if any cdkey information came along when I did the purchase and I don't see anything there either.

Is anyone else having this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I have it installed on multiple computers and have no issues.  Maybe you selected register your account when installing?  I got a prompt to register my account each time I installed, and was confused too because I never received a CD key, but that was because I bought from battle.net.  After installing the only prompt I got on another pc was the EULA.

The games 100% complete on both and which one is giving you issues?

Comment: i will try again when i get home thnx

Comment: Any Luck SarmenHB?

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding you do not need a cd key to install the game and can install it on as many computers as you like because you need to use an account to login to play the game either way.

One way to do this is to go to www.battle.net and login.
Next go to the account and select the game you would like to install.
If you have already purchased the game online (or entered the cd key from a retail purchase) you should have an option to download and install the game.

Hope that helps.