# Can I play Diablo III with one disc, two different battle.net accounts and two computers?

Tags: diablo-iii, battle.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do I need to own Diablo III to download and install the game?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/70374/do-i-need-to-own-diablo-iii-to-download-and-install-the-game)

Basically, my friend has a Diablo III disc which I plan to borrow, and I started my own battle.net account, so can I play on a different battle.net account, on a different computer, with the same disc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The disc just has the game data, to play you need to have a registered copy of Diablo 3 on your battle.net account.

Your friend should already have registered the key that came with his disk to his account so you will not be able to use it with your account, but you can use the disc to install the game on your own computer if you want and buy a digital copy of the game for you own battle.net account.

Comment: So you can't register two accounts to one disc?

Comment: @Devin: The disk is meaningless as far as D3 is concerned. What really matters is the key that comes with the disk. This is registered against your Battle.net account and is what allows you to login *anywhere* that has D3 installed. If you buy D3 online via Blizzard you will get it registered against your account and then you can quite happily use your friends disk to install the game or download it.

Comment: Okay, I also heard about the game coming with three trial codes. If I enter one of those three trial codes that came with my friends game, then will that work? And i haven't registered my battle.net account to any game yet.

Comment: @Devin: Like I said, you can install D3 wherever you want using the CD you just can't play it at all without having a Battle.net account that has the game activated on it. D3 is an always-online game. You will be able to play it with the trail code, though obviously only with whatever restrictions are on a trial account (I honestly don't know).

Comment: Okay, thank you. Sorry if I was sounding stubborn. I'll go look up the trial restrictions.